# Rust struct field generic over Deref<Target=Self>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build Rust code that manipulates a recursive (tree-like) data structure. Naively, one could define it as

```
struct ALinkedList {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Self>>
}
```

To experiment with different memory layouts and separate algorithm design from storage, I'd like to generalize the definition to something like

```
struct ALinkedList<D: Deref<Target=Self>> {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<D>
}
```

but when trying to construct an instance of ALinkedList, I get

```
64 |     let t: ALinkedList<Box<_>> = ALinkedList{value: 0, next: Some(Box::new(ALinkedList{value: 0, next: None}))};
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cyclic type of infinite size
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to make these recursive type definitions work in Rust?
2. If not, what other design patterns can I use to represent a tree-like struct without hardcoding how its children are stored and dereferenced in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Rust can't deal with infinitely deep generics currently.

There's a way around using GAT (Generic Associated Types), unfortunately still nightly-only ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c74554985fcb6592f69fb61d38e96bd)):

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]
use std::ops::Deref;

struct ALinkedList<A: Allocator> {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<A::Allocated<Self>>
}
impl<A: Allocator> ALinkedList<A> {
    fn set_next(&mut self, next: Self) {
        self.next = Some(next.into()) // create a new allocation via From
    }
}

trait Allocator {
    type Allocated<T>: Deref<Target=T> + From<T>;
}

struct BoxAllocator;
impl Allocator for BoxAllocator {
    type Allocated<T> = Box<T>;
}

fn main() {
    let mut t: ALinkedList<BoxAllocator> = ALinkedList{value: 0, next: Some(Box::new(ALinkedList{value: 0, next: None}))};
    t.set_next(ALinkedList{value: 1, next: None});
}
```

Comment: The `allocate` trait method doesn't seem to be used anywhere in your code

Comment: It was intended to be the way to create allocations from within the LinkedList impl. Looking at it I tihnk it's cleaner to use From. Updated code and added example on how it works.

Comment: Thanks! I've been playing around with this and tried to replace the struct with an enum, and in some cases it works fine just like your example, but in others it fails to compile: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ac6a9816894e82d88aae3dc5ef09a40). Specifically, `enum CLinkedList<A: Allocator> {  Head, Next(A::Allocated<Self>) }` fails to compile and throws `overflow evaluating the requirement '...: Sized'` . Is this a compiler bug due to GATs being incomplete, or me misunderstanding something about sizedness?

Comment: That's indeed a strange error. Looks like a bug to me, file a Rust issue!